# Have Restlet working alongside HTTP Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, restlet, java-server

In an existing Java SE project, my colleagues had implemented a bunch of web services in Restlet, relying on an internal server implementation. This turned out to be inadequate in the long run, so we migrated to a server engine based on jetty 9, with the great drawback that [Restlet did not support it back then](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/793). This didn't stop the team, and now quite a few "raw" HTTP servlets were implemented with our business logic.

As this turned out to become a frustrating way of implementing web services, we now wish to have Restlet back for future services and make them work alongside these servlets. My research revealed no big clues on making such an integration, with the exception that a [Request and Response wrapper to the HTTP counterparts](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/71) is still under way, and marked as unplanned. Furthermore, the amount of existing work on these servlets is significant, which is why I'm putting conversion to Restlet resources as a last resort.

To sum the question up, how can I make a Restlet Application work alongside HTTP servlets in the same server? Is there a way in Java SE to attach a Rest application to a servlet container? Or thinking the other way around, is there a way to attach raw servlets to an Application with some extra resort, like a Servlet-to-Resource wrapper that could be applied to any HTTP servlet? Any feasible, non-invasive solution may be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `org.restlet.ext.servlet` package is compatible with the Java SE edition of Restlet, even though it is listed in the Java EE group. Here are the steps one would follow:

Create a [`ServletAdapter`](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServletAdapter.html), which converts HTTP servlet requests and responses to high-level restlet representations. The documentation itself suggests to encapsulate it.

```
public class RestletHttpServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ServletAdapter adapter;
    private final Restlet restlet;

    public RestletHttpServlet(Restlet restlet) {
        this.restlet = restlet;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        this.adapter = new ServletAdapter(getServletContext());
        this.restlet.setContext(this.adapter.getContext());
        this.adapter.setNext(this.restlet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.adapter.service(req, resp);
    }
}
```

With this helper class, simply create new restlets and attach them with the servlet API (using context handlers here):

```
Restlet myRestlet = ...
ServletContextHandler cHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
cHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new RestletHttpServlet(myRestlet)), "/myRestlet/*");
ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();
contextHandlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{cHandler});
server.setHandler(contextHandlers);
```

Routers, resources and template paths seem to work as well. Making the first restlet an `Application` is also possible and often helpful for a complete context initialization.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to embed a Restlet application within a servlet container. In this case, you should use the extension `org.restlet.ext.servlet`. The latter provides an entry servlet that dispatches requests to server resources of a Restlet application

See this link for more details about how to configure this feature: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.tutorial.markdown/02_Server_Side/04_Server_Deployment/02_Servlet_Deployment.md.

Comment: We have a standalone Java SE server application, and `org.restlet.ext.servlet` is for the EE version of Restlet. Unless there is a work-around to having that work on the SE version, I'm afraid it won't help.

Comment: I have read again your question and it's clearer now. Could you give me what your servlets exactly use from request and response (especially headers)? Then I could provide you an implementation for this... We could work incrementally and contribute back this work to the Restlet `ext.servlet` extension. Does this approach suit you?

Comment: Well, they only seem to retrieve arbitrary query string parameters and send response entities by printing a String and setting an appropriate content type. This is no longer a greater priority for me, but you can let me know if you take any initiative.

Comment: Ok. I'll provide you some stuff to do that soon ;-) I don't forget your request...